# Android Hashmap interaction

Tags: android, string, hashmap

I am attempting to set up a simple Morse encoder using a hashmap in android.  Putting values in the hashmap seems pretty straightforward like so:

```
    HashMap<String, String> translate = new HashMap<String, String>();

//initializing translate
translate.put("A",".-");
//same for all letters of alphabet and numbers
```

However I am having difficulty finding an effective way to utilize the data of the key values for export to another method.  I plan to use these values in a string method and simply display it on the phone screen for the user when they type a letter.  For example, if they type in "A" the hash map will be queried for "A" and return a ".-".  I have never worked with hashmaps before and can't find a suitable example.

Any help on how to access these keys within an android environment will be appreciated!

Comment: I'm unclear about your question.  Is it not answered by a glance at the documentation?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: I viewed the android doc for hashmap but I really need a good example of what I can do with the result.  As in can the key value be used as a raw string or do I need to convert it to something else?

Comment: An example of what you can do with a string ...?  Do you perhaps have a question that has nothing to do with HashMaps?

Comment: I think what I mean is if I take a value from the hashmap to use, can it be used as is?  Right now I am just using strings but what if I put something in like a URL link, or something much more complicated than a simple string.  If I query the hashmap for A = -URL link-, will that result be literally whatever is the value for A?  If I use a get method for the hashmap, the result is literally what I put in for the value / key pairs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [HashMap.get()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29), so:

```
translate.get("A");  // returns ".-"
```

The object returned is exactly the same as the object supplied in the 2nd argument to `put()`. So if you put a `URL` in (and the `Map` is suitably typed) you will get the same `URL` instance returned from `get()`.

Comment: I thought about using the get method but does it return the key of ".-" in ASCII?  A string?

Comment: It will return what you put into the Map, so in this case a yes it will be a String. What do you need here?

Comment: What I will eventually need is a way to act on what is returned.  Such as if I get back a ".-" do this vs if I get back a "-.-" do something else instead.  Right now I am just attempting to master access in and out of the hashmap.

Answer (score 0):

HashMap has keySet and entrySet(). You may start from here. Here is javadoc for complete list of methods in [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). Here is an [example](http://hanuska.blogspot.com/2006/08/improved-map-iteration_13.html) on how to use those methods.